# NSIS make D: the default installation path

Tags: electron, nsis

I have an electron app, I want the default installation path to be D: if it exist, instead of C:

My current installer.nsh file is:

```
Section
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetFileAttributes(t "D:\")i .r0'
    
    IntCmp $0 -1 NoDInstalled DriveDInstalled
    
    NoDInstalled:
        StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES\"
        Goto ContinueInstallation

    DriveDInstalled:
        StrCpy $INSTDIR "D:\"
        Goto ContinueInstallation
    
  ContinueInstallation:
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR
SectionEnd
```

I have a D: external drive connected to my computer and the default is still C:

Would love some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should set the default `$InstDir` in `.onInit`, not in a `Section`.
- You should provide 3 jump labels to `IntCmp`.
- You should not install to the root of `$PROGRAMFILES`

---

```
!macro customInit
System::Call 'kernel32::GetFileAttributes(t "D:\")i.r0'
${If} $0 <> -1
  StrCpy $INSTDIR "D:\"
${Else}
   StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES\$(^Name)"
${EndIf}
!macroend
```

In real NSIS you would just

```
Function .onInit
!insertmacro customInit
FunctionEnd
```

but since you are using electron I have no idea where you actually put this macro, [the documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis.html#custom-nsis-script) is not clear if it is in installer.nsh or somewhere else. [Their code](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/packages/app-builder-lib/templates/nsis/installSection.nsh) makes it look like it should be somewhere else, you probably have to ask them directly for support if you can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: It worked! I changed to macro to preInit and added these lines at the end of the macro:  
  `SetRegView 64  
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation $INSTDIR  
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation $INSTDIR  
  SetRegView 32  
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation $INSTDIR  
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation $INSTDIR`  
  
And electron-builder is taking care of calling the macro (I didn't need the Function .onInit)  
Thank you!